# Python send_keys method is not sending the desired values

Tags: python, selenium, headless

I am writing a script that will fill out a form. It sends a string with a certain value to the text field where the value should be entered. However, while the text field always becomes entered, the characters sometimes become scrambled. For instance, in one field, the value to be entered was:

420420420420420

Yet, the screenshot from the filled out field yielded this value:

420404204204202

Why is this? Is there an alternative method that can be used to avoid this issue?

Specifically, these lines of code cause the most issues:

```
client.find_element_by_id("nnaerb").send_keys(checkout_parameters[9])
client.find_element_by_id("credit_card_month").send_keys(checkout_parameters[10])
client.find_element_by_id("credit_card_year").send_keys(checkout_parameters[11])
```

Comment: You should include the part of your script that generates this behavior.

Comment: I added the lines that caused the most trouble above. The client is just a Selenium browser object.

Comment: cant unfortunately guess  the cause with the info you provided, alternatively you could use : driver.execute_script($().val()), to use jQuery to populate the text box and see if its not flaky

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm that's weird that it would send them in the incorrect order. You could try something like this maybe:

```
for key in checkout_parameters[9]:
    client.find_element_by_id("nnaerb").send_keys(key)
```

This way you specify them to be sent one at a time in order?

Or you could really break it down and use `ActionChains`:

```
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
action_chains = ActionChains(client)
action_chains.move_to_element(client.find_element_by_id("nnaerb"))
action_chains.click()
for key in checkout_parameters[9]:
    action_chains.key_down(key)
    action_chains.key_up(key)
action_chains.perform()
```

## edit

From [selenium documentation](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains.ActionChains.key_down) it says with regard to `.key_down()`:

> Should only be used with modifier keys (Control, Alt and Shift).

So it looks like using `ActionChains` would be like:

```
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
action_chains = ActionChains(client)
action_chains.move_to_element(client.find_element_by_id("nnaerb"))
action_chains.click()
for key in checkout_parameters[9]:
    action_chains.send_keys(key)
action_chains.perform()
```

Which doesn't look like it would yield better results here than my first code block.

Comment: Just to clarify this for loop is the equivalent to sending the characters one by one to the text field right?

Comment: @AndrewWang That was the intent, yes!

Comment: Thank you so much! I just created a method and the problem fixed itself!

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes card input fields can be a little tricky and at the speed selenium uses 'keys' is a perhaps too fast in some cases. I'd suggest giving the below a try :)

Setting the real value with Javascript to the given element, it may not appear on screen, but values do in-fact get attributed on.

```
nnaerb = driver.find_element_by_id("nnaerb")
month = driver.find_element_by_id("credit_card_month")
year = driver.find_element_by_id("credit_card_year")

driver.execute_script("arguments[0].value = " + checkout_parameters[9] + ";", nnaerb) 
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].value = " + checkout_parameters[10] + ";", month) 
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].value = " + checkout_parameters[11] + ";", year)
```